# How to disable the magnifier on a UITextField in Objective C Programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

My TableView Cell has a textfield. On long pressing on the text field, the magnifier appears and all the UI elements start flickers like dim dip light and then disappear sometimes. Is there any way I could enable the user to input data but not allow long press magnifier?? Please help.